# How to run a custom theme on Streamlit?

Tags: python, css, streamlit

I’m trying to create a custom coloured theme for an app I’m making but for some reason it’s not working.

Here’s a link to my github with the `config.toml` file:
https://github.com/daniellambert95/streamlit_app_v1/blob/main/.streamlit/config.toml

Note that I have added the file to the `.streamlit/` folder.

Here’s a link to the live app I created but as you can see the standard theme is activated. Although, when I run it on a local host the theme I created works…

https://share.streamlit.io/daniellambert95/streamlit_app_v1/main/main.py

If anyone could help it would be highly appreciated!

Comment: This question is not reproducible, i cloned your github repo and deployed it and the theme works. you can see it [here](https://share.streamlit.io/leorrose/streamlit_app_v1/main/main.py). I would suggest to redeploy you app or cleaning the cache in your browser. Also note that the font should be 'sans serif' and not 'sans-serif'.

Comment: Hey thanks for the comment. I managed to get it working by rebooting my streamlit app from the dashboard.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reboot your streamlit app from your dashboard

Comment: Wow, thanks @ahmedshahriar. I didn't realise it was as simple as that :D

Comment: I'm glad it was helpful, you're welcome!

Comment: @ahmedshahriar what that means? reboot from the dashboard?

Comment: @H.H when you are logged in on your streamlit dashboard you will see a list of your apps. And there's a 3 dot associated with every app, click it and there should be an option to "reboot"